# What is the null item in this XML pipeline?

Tags: powershell

Consider the following XML document:

```
$xml = [xml] "<root><value>one</value><value>two</value></root>"
```

And then print the values (with some prefix/suffix):

```
$xml.root.value | %{"*$_*"}
*one*
*two*
```

So far so good. However, if the element does not exist, a null item is propagated trough the pipeline:

```
$xml.root.foo | %{"*$_*"}
**
```

Why is that? Is there any way to avoid this extra check:

```
$xml.root.foo | ?{$_} | %{"*$_*"}
```

It's easy to forget and it seems error prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn off the silent fail on missing properties use `Set-StrictMode -Version Latest` e.g.:

```
PS> $xml = [xml] "<root><value>one</value><value>two</value></root>"
PS> $xml.root.foo | %{"*$_*"}
**
PS> Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
PS> $xml.root.foo | %{"*$_*"}
Property 'foo' cannot be found on this object. Make sure that it exists.
At line:1 char:1
+ $xml.root.foo | %{"*$_*"}
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict
```

Note that this will also catch references to non-existing variables. I highly recommend using `Set-StrictMode` in this manner as it can save you debugging time for larger scripts.

Comment: I see. However, in my actual use case where this example comes from, the <value> elements can indeed be missing (it's not a typo) and I want to loop over all <value> elements or do nothing when missing. Is there a better way to do it other than my ?{$_} filter?

Comment: With XML in PowerShell V1/V2, if there are multiple elements of that same name then yes, you have to iterate explicity.  In PowerShell V3 this has been fixed so that `$xml.root.value` outputs `one` and `two`.  Some call this automatic unrolling, others call it implicit foreach.

Comment: I have V2 and the iteration over $xml.root.value works fine. My only snag is that I need to throw in the counter-intuitive filter to guard against $null when there are no <value> elements.

Answer (score 0):

Keith is right that you are getting a silent error which is allowing the null element to be propagated down the pipeline. I am also a strong advocate for scripting ***PowerShell*** in ***StrictMode***.

Here is my solution to your problem (which will work with ***StrictMode*** enabled).

If you do quick ***Get-Member*** on ***$xml*** you will see that it is of type [System.Xml.XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) (subsequently elements will be of type ***System.Xml.XmlElement***). Using the ***SelectNodes*** function we can get an ***XmlNodeList*** for a given ***XPath***. So the example file above can be written as follows:

```
$xml.SelectNodes("//root/value")  | % {"*" + $_.'#text'+ "*"}
```

This will give you the desired output.

```
*one*
*two*
```

If we start looking for non existent node:

```
$xml.SelectNodes("//root/value")  | % {"*" + $_.'#text'+ "*"}
```

You will get no response, as is expected.